# How to disable a payment with react-paypal-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway

I switched from react-paypal-button-v2 to react-paypal-js.

Before i could disable payments inside my options with disableFunding: 'card'
but it no longer working with react-paypal-js

So I'm kinda confused where to set it up.
Inside my initialOptions or in my PayPalButton as a props?

```
const initialOptions = {
  'client-id': 'test',
  currency: 'EUR',
  intent: 'capture',
};

<PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
    <PayPalButtons/>
</PayPalScriptProvider>
```

Edit:

```
const initialOptions = {
  'client-id': 'test',
  currency: 'EUR',
  intent: 'capture',
  'disable-funding': 'card',
};
```

It's not working for me and without single quotes it's not working bcs I can't use that for an opject with hyphen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-paypal-js supports all the script config options [the JS SDK itself does](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/).

Add `disable-funding: 'card'` in the options to PayPalScriptProvider.

Comment: Please check my edit. Without quotes it runs into errors and with quotes it's not working. I still see the credit card.

Comment: I tested and it works. Try with a minimal example somewhere else such as codesandbox.

Comment: I' had the other question with the currency problem aswell. Now both working fine. Bcs before i had it with 2 components. I had my App.js component wrapped with PayPalScriptProvider. Now I made the PayPalScriptProvider to my payment component and disable-funding and currency working. So the wrapping of the App.js is not neccessary?

Comment: It needs to be a parent of PayPalButtons or anything else using it, that's the only requirement as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the funding-method in the 'fundingSource' in the  component's props.

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HrLf.png)

The button will display only the specified method.

Comment: Its good your helping other but your answer can b improve please check this [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Add **disableFunding: 'card'** in the options to PayPalScriptProvider.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).